# Decision tree support both category and numeric features at the same time, in Python, is there any?

Tags: python, decision-tree

There are decision trees of each: 
`from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, DecisionTreeRegressor`

But are there any decision tree support both category and numeric features at the same time? Or one-hot is the only standard solution?

Comment: one-hot is the only standard solution

Comment: for many sklearn models the standard is one-hot encoding, afaik only few implementations (Microsoft's lightgbm for example) have a support for this stuff.